# Mysql group by a column and get the rows only with the maximum value of the third column

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have managed to construct a table such as below from my data:

How can I get the maximum of the third column B for each beam number? I want to get rid of other rows. Any help is appreciated.

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeYG8.png)

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by beam_num order by b desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have posted the image text was just fine
In mysql 5.x there are no window functions.

The aggregation fucntion for A, B,,C D you have to check , there are needed if 2 or more B have the maximum.

```
SELECT 
    t1.`Beam_Num`, MAX(`A`), MAX(`B`), MAX(`C`), MAX(`D`)
FROM
    table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(B) maxb, Beam_Num
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY Beam_Num) t2 ON t1.Beam_Num = t2.Beam_Num
        AND t1.B = t2.maxb
GROUP BY t1.Beam_Num;
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`Beam_Num` int, `A` NUMERIC, `B` NUMERIC, `C` NUMERIC, `D` numeric)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`Beam_Num`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`)
VALUES
    (10, 4760.0, 491190.0, 223.0, 0.482),
    (10, 4760.0, 528769.0, 205.0, 0.444),
    (1000, 1941.0, 143560.0, -56.0, 0.2),
    (1000, 1941.0, 113815.0, -19.0, 0.15),
    (1001, 2695.0, 115663.0, 95.0, 0.56),
    (1003, 2250.0, 473762.0, 96.0, 0.555),
    (1003, 2250.0, 474130.0, 185.0, 0.555),
    (1005, 11861.0, 457673.0, -1056.0, 0.333),
    (1008, 948.0, 20471.0, 77.0, 0.5),
    (1008, 948.0, 102978.0, 92.0, 0.375),
    (1009, 3308.0, 250528.0, 261.0, 0.715)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
t1.`Beam_Num`, MAX(`A`), MAX(`B`), MAX(`C`), MAX(`D`)
FROm 
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(B) maxb,Beam_Num FROM table1 GROUP BY Beam_Num) t2
    ON t1.Beam_Num =
 t2.Beam_Num AND t1.B = t2.maxb
 GROUP BY t1.Beam_Num;

| Beam_Num | MAX(`A`) | MAX(`B`) | MAX(`C`) | MAX(`D`) |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 10       | 4760     | 528769   | 205      | 0        |
| 1000     | 1941     | 143560   | -56      | 0        |
| 1001     | 2695     | 115663   | 95       | 1        |
| 1003     | 2250     | 474130   | 185      | 1        |
| 1005     | 11861    | 457673   | -1056    | 0        |
| 1008     | 948      | 102978   | 92       | 0        |
| 1009     | 3308     | 250528   | 261      | 1        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just run a query using the `MAX` aggregate function and the `GROUP BY` clause as follows:

```sql
SELECT Beam_Num, A, MAX(B), C, D
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Beam_Num;
```

Replace `table_name` with the name of the table you want to run the query on.